# Как правильно в Gulp 4 настроить browserSync reload html, js?

Tags: веб-программирование, gulp

Не получается настроить reload html и js. Где у меня ошибка?

```
const
  gulp          = require('gulp'),
  sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
  browsersync   = require("browser-sync").create(),
  concat        = require('gulp-concat'), 
  concatCSS     = require('gulp-concat-css'),
  uglify        = require('gulp-uglifyjs'), 
  cssnano       = require('gulp-cssnano'), 
  rename        = require('gulp-rename'),
  del           = require('del'),
  imagemin      = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  pngquant      = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
  cache         = require('gulp-cache'),
  autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  htmlmin       = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
  gutil         = require( 'gulp-util' ),
  ftp           = require( 'vinyl-ftp' );

function gulpSass() {
  return gulp
    .src('assets/sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: "expanded" }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], {cascade: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function browserSync(done) {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./"
    },
    port: 3000,
    notify: false
  });
  done();
}

function clean() {
  return del(["dist"]);
}

function clear() {
  return cache.clearAll();
}

function watchFiles(done) {
  gulp.watch('assets/sass/**/*.sass', gulp.parallel(gulpSass));
  gulp.watch('assets/css/**/*.css', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch("*.html", browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('assets/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
  done();
}


const watch = gulp.parallel(watchFiles, browserSync);

exports.clean = clean;
exports.clear = clear;
exports.watch = watch;
```

Comment: 100 лет не пользовался гулпом. перешел нынче на вэбпак (чего и вам советую), но, насколько помню, в `baseDir` нужно указать полный домен (или localhost) с http(s)://

Comment: перешел и я на вебпак, но есть проекты, в которых вебпак не нужен. 
В baseDir не обязательно указывать полный путь.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена добавлением отдельной функции перезагрузки

```
function reload(done) {
  browserSync.reload();
  done();
}
```

Comment: Так все таки `reload` или `browserSync.reload` ? И где ее инициировать?